# Flutter Project Launch Issue with VsCode

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, flutter-web

I use my phone as an emulator while developing applications with Flutter.
After updating to the Flutter 2 version, Web Folder added to Flutter file directory, I know that.
but i can't run the project

Here I started the classic flutter counter app and the result:

[image]

```
Launching lib\main.dart on MI 5 in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code -1
Exited (sigterm)
```

I searched for a solution on the internet but could not solve this stupid error

how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Check this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31971

Answer (score 1):

Connect to Internet
run `flutter clean`
then `flutter pub get`
then `flutter run` .

This might help, try it out.
This error usually comes when some files are pending download or so.

Comment: unfortunately,
The first thing that comes to my mind

Answer (score 0):

if I use flutter run command from terminal

```
Launching lib\main.dart on MI 5 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        76,3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code -1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but,
Try changing `minSdkVersion` from 16 to 21

You can find this property in `./android/app/build.gradle`

Then do a flutter clean and run the project

If this does not work there might be issue with the emulator or the flutter version.